# Trix from Latin

Tags: etymology

Is the Latin term *Trix* for a female person related to the term *turning tricks* as related to prostitution?  I have reviewed the origination of *turning tricks* as noted on this site. However, it did not mention anything about the Latin origin of *Trix* itself.  It only mentions the French term *trique*.

Comment: Trix are for kids.

Comment: Essentially it's just a feminine suffix added to the basic agentive -_tor_ which compesses it into -_trix_, a feminine agentive. Nothing special, just Latin morphology.

Comment: No. Even in the case of *peccatrix* , a female sinner, it's entirely coincidental.

Comment: Silly Robusto. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trix_%28cereal%29

Comment: The Latin, or at least medieval Latin, for prostitute is _meretrix_. As JL and Hugh say, however, the -trix part is just the feminine suffix, not the part that does the meaning work. Note that a feminine suffix and "a term for a female person" are not the same thing; would you say that _Ess_ is the English word for a female person just because we have (or had) Authoress and Adulteress?

Comment: This site is called English Language & Usage, not Latin Language & Usage. If you're interested in Latin then support [this site proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75409/latin-language), but such questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 9):

The noun *trick* and the suffix *-trix* are not related in English. If they share a common origin, it would predate their Latin origin:

*[trick](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=trick&allowed_in_frame=0)*

> (n.)
> early 15c., "a cheat, a mean ruse,"
> from Old North French trique
> "trick, deceit, treachery, cheating,"
> from trikier "to deceive, to
> cheat," variant of Old French trichier "to cheat, trick, deceive," of
> uncertain origin,
> probably from Vulgar Latin *triccare,
> from Latin
> tricari "be evasive, shuffle,"
> from tricæ "trifles, nonsense, a tangle
> of difficulties," of unknown origin.
>
> Meaning "a roguish prank" is recorded from 1580s; sense of "the art of
> doing something" is first attested 1610s.
> Meaning "***prostitute's
> client" is first attested 1915***; earlier it was U.S. slang for "a
> robbery" (1865).
> To do the trick "accomplish one's purpose" is from
> 1812;
> to miss a trick "fail to take advantage of opportunity" is from
> 1889; from 1872 in reference to playing the card-game of whist, which
> might be the original literal sense.
> Trick-or-treat is recorded from
> 1942. Trick question is from 1907.
>
> *<sub>etymonline.com **emphasis** added</sub>*

*[-trix](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-trix&allowed_in_frame=0)*

> fem. agential suffix,
> from Latin, corresponding to masc. -tor (see
> -or).
>
> *<sub>etymonline.com</sub>*

Comment: Now THAT's a good answer!  I'd give it 2 +1's if I could.  I feel very educated on the meaning and history of the word "trick"! :-)