# Origin of "Trick or Treat"

Tags: etymology, halloween

In North America, **trick or treating** is a Halloween custom, in which children go door-to-door to say *"trick or treat"* as a way of asking for treats. I'm wondering if there are any common or at least understandable replacements for it.

Additionally, after searching *[trick or treat](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22trick%20or%20treat%22)* on EL&U, I'd like to expand my original question and include a request for its origin. Its phrasing presents "trick" as an alternative to "treat"; but, giving out *tricks* doesn't seem to be prevalent. Hopefully "trick" wasn't added without reason; so, I'm *also* looking for the **origin** of the Halloween phrase, *trick or treat.*

Comment: "Extortion with menaces"?

Comment: @Tower of Tesia "Curse or Candy?"

Comment: Why do you need a replacement??

Comment: Perhaps if you edited the question, and *also* ask whether the chant "trick or treat" has always existed, or when did it begin to become popular? Why do kids chant "treat" and not "sweet" or "candy"? When was the first time the phrase appeared in print? Why is it that specific order, why is it never *trick or treat*?  When did the term *trick* mean something unpleasant? Does the "trick" in *tick or treat* stand for nasty surprise or does it stand for "joke"? etc. etc.

Comment: BTW the phrase for native speakers is *very* understandable, no one has any problems understanding the request, or threat, if you prefer.

Comment: related: [Trix from Latin](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250624/trix-from-latin/250626#250626) and [Is there a season's greeting for Halloween?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46775/is-there-a-seasons-greeting-for-halloween)

Comment: "I'm gonna make ya an offer ya can't refuse."

Comment: The meaning is simply "give me a treat or I'll give you a trick".  Halloween was previously known by terms such as "mischief night" or "devil's night", and youngsters (and those pretending to be so) would perform "practical jokes" (such as overturning outhouses) on their neighbors.  The "treat", then, was a bribe to forgo the "trick".

Comment: I suggested *ALSO*, the original request should remain, you got answers for that part, and it's unfair to turn the tables now and say to users their answers are completely off topic, they weren't when they were posted. Patience when it was only one answer, but three?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for pointing that out. I agree that deleting my original question is unfair to answerers. Had I seen your comment sooner I'd have fixed it myself; but seeing that you beat me to it, I'm very thankful.

Comment: Only words can have etymologies, not phrases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a very common one, but anyways; consider the Canadian regional ***Halloween Apples!***

> In some parts of Canada, children sometimes say "Halloween apples"
>   instead of "trick or treat." This probably originated when the toffee
>   apple was a popular type of candy. Apple-giving in much of Canada,
>   however, has been taboo since the 1960s when stories (of almost
>   certainly questionable authenticity) appeared of razor blades hidden
>   inside Halloween apples; parents began to check over their children's
>   "loot" for safety before allowing them to eat it. In Quebec, children
>   also go door to door on Halloween. However, in French speaking
>   neighbourhoods, instead of "Trick or treat?", they will simply say
>   "Halloween", though in tradition it used to be La charité
>   s'il-vous-plaît ("Charity, please"). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trick-or-treating)

Alternately, consider the suggestion in my comment above, ***Curse or Candy!***

> *Children go from place to place and say "curse or candy!" [Heppy
>    Halloween](https://ladybusinessblog.wordpress.com/2009/11/01/heppy-helloveen/)*